# What is the best way to upload a csv from local machine onto the backend (Using Angular for front-end and Django for backend)

Tags: django, angular, frontend, backend

I want the user to be able to upload a csv, and this (after some modification) gets stored in the back-end server. I was currently passing a POST request with the csv as a string. I think this may fail for very large csv's. What is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [form with a FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/). This will result in an "Open File" dialog in the browser, and uploading of the file.

(This answer ignores the Angular tag, it's straight Django).

Comment: I am handling the front-end with angular8. So I want the forms and all in the angular files